# Deploying blog with Octopress on github

Tags: github, rubygems, jekyll, blogs, octopress

#### What i'm doing:

I have been trying to deploy an *Octopress Blog* using github as host and jekyll and liquid for designing purpose.
I have installed all necessary file like gitBash for windows , Jekyll , Octopress ,RubyGem and even DevKit. I can see my blog preview using `'rake preview'` and its coming completely fine as it should. Also `'rake generate'` and `'rake deploy`' worked fine on gitBash and gave me a positive reply.

### **Am unclear with 3 things:**

1. Do i have to copy my `_deploy` folder to github repository.
2. Getting 2 error on GitBash:
              1.Change machine code to 65001(For which i have used `chcp 65001` on cmd)
              2.Permission Denied on public key when using `rake deploy` command.
3. Also i see a ruby gem error sometimes like Polling for changes and then i have to use ctrl+C to get out of terminal
   I can give you many links for tutorials too but if there's any one who can help me practically socially;p then it will be real help.

Also when am on my source folder from gitbash i typed git push -u origin master am getting following two errors.

[image: Thank you]

Comment: You're asking three questions here. Close this question and ask three question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: @DavidJacquel asking three question separately will not make people understand where am stuck..and are my tags inappropriate? because all i am asking about is related to all of them

Comment: First question is Octopress use, second is GitBash problem and the third is ruby over windows. I use linux ans I will not answer to the second and third questions. I certainly have an answer for your first question. You will not get any valuable answer if you're not trying to ask question in the right way see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DavidJacquel No offense but i think i asked too much and specially not at right place as you say.I will close this question.

Comment: And if you open an Octopress specific question, I'll be pleased to answer it.